# How to stop sqlite3 database being replaced when the app using it is updated?

Tags: android-sqlite

I am currently developing a mobile application in Python that uses a sqlite3 database in order to save data. However, if I rebuild and redeploy the application to my mobile device, the existing sqlite3 .db file on the mobile device understandably gets replaced with a brand new one. Is there any way to prevent this replacement from happening? I only plan on using this app for personal use, so it's not that urgent an issue, it would really only be convenient. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to replicate what Android Apps written in Java or Kotlin use.

That is they (typically via [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) which is described as *A helper class to manage database creation and version management.*), check to see if the file exists at the expected location/path.

- if not then the database (empty bar sqlite_master and android_metadata) is created and the `onCreate` method is invoked, allowing the user defined components (tables, indexes, views, triggers to be created).
- if so then the database is instead opened.

*This is a simplfied, overview, as it undertakes other things such as checking the user_version against a coded version, catering for onUpgrade or the rarely used onDowngrade methods to be utilised.*

As such you probably just need to have similar logic to detect if the file itself exists (this as simple as this would be prone to failure should the file, for some reason, not be an actual SQLite file).